# Convert normal url to blob url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a live streaming url which I want to play in browser. Also I want to convert this url to blob url - **blob:http://** in this format. So when someone opens inspect element, they will see the blob url address instead of the original url. I don't have any problem with the video playing part. It's playing nicely. I need help with the blob url part. My code till now.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hls.js@latest"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<video id="video" width="320" height="240"></video>

<script>

    if(Hls.isSupported()) {
        var video = document.getElementById('video');
        var hls = new Hls();
        hls.loadSource("https://video-dev.github.io/streams/x36xhzz/x36xhzz.m3u8");
        hls.attachMedia(video);
        hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED,function() {
            video.play();
        });
    };

 </script>
```

So, right now if I check the inspect element, I can easily view the video url.

Comment: F12 network tab will still show the real address though, right?  If this is an attempt at obfuscation it might not be worth the effort.

Comment: @DaveS any idea then, how to hide the url from inspect element or show the encoded url in inspect element?